# Visual Studio 2008 show FULL stack trace after stack overflow

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stack-overflow

I have a running C++ project that has had a stack overflow whilst I was running it under the debugger within the IDE.

Visual Studio 2008 has taken it upon itself to truncate the stack trace of the overflowing thread (well hey if we're gonna do that why check for overflows at all?).

Is there some view option or debugging option that will show me the root of this thread's calls?

**So in essence apart from offering me reasons why a stack trace can be corrupted etc (shall I disable my AV and run memtest86 as well?) does anyone have ACTUAL INFORMATION about the truncation of stack traces in Visual Studio 2008?**

Comment: Maybe as you overflowed the stack, you overwrote something crucial, so the debugger simply wasn't *able* to trace back through the stack any more.

Comment: I agree that such corruption can occur, however the whole point of a stack overflow is to stop execution BEFORE we lost something. Not only that, regardless of what garbage may be in the stack, it still exists in memory.

Comment: check all memory functions and loops..

Comment: The debugger is your friend! Add a breakpoint _before_ the crash, and then step by step go through your code until it happens. It's tedious and can take a lot of time, but might be necessary. Unless you of course find somewhere where you pass e.g. a pointer to a local variable or overwrite an array or some such.

Comment: "however the whole point of a stack overflow is to stop execution BEFORE we lost something" -> I do not think that is how a debugger works

Comment: "I do not think that is how a debugger works" -> There is a difference between your runtime (which throws an exception if it notices you are about to push something onto the stack when it's full) and the debugger (which catches unhandled exceptions and attempts to disassemble the runtime data and display it in context of your sourcecode).

Comment: "The debugger is your friend! Add a breakpoint before the crash" -> Before the stack overflow... so in other words at the root of the stack trace I'm looking at? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to keep your stack small enough from the start, so that the stack overflow happens earlier. You didn't want one megabtyte of repeated functions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a big stack AND avoid stack overflow due to some simple recursion bug, use TLS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686749(v=vs.85).aspx.

Allocate one slot when the process starts and then increment the value of the slot using TlsGetValue and TlsSetValue and then check if it's exceeded, then break into the debugger or do some other "pause" in your supposedly faulty function.

It won't work for 3rd party code without hacks, but it worked well for me to work around the limitation and also being pretty light.